# Selecting and Copy/Cut certain row/column in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

Is there any way to mark/block certain column/row by using the formula in Microsoft Excel?
e.g. i wanna copy only the odd rows and it takes me a long time to copy/paste it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your sheet with below formula:

```
= MOD(Row(); 2)
```

Now You can `Filter` that row to `1` for odd rows and then copy your data.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that avoids a delimiter that might not suit your locale is:

```
=ISODD(ROW())
```

in a spare column copied down to suit. Then filter that column to select `TRUE` and copy what's visible.